# Email in background of Android App

Tags: android

I have used code on this link to send email in background of  my app: 
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)
The problem is this worked fine when I debugged my application in android version 2.3.4 HTC Amaze 4G
but when i installed the same application on android version 4.2.2 Samsung GT-I8852 the email is not sent.
Can anyone think of a reason of why this happened as I don't know where to look for a fault?

Comment: Did you check device log?

Comment: Are you sure mobile internet is activated properly? Are you able to manually configure the gmail and send an email?

Comment: Yes I have checked the internet connectivity before sending the email and I can manually send the email to any account using my gmail account from the app.

Comment: Add logging throughout the actual implementation code so that you can see that it is making a genuine attempt, and what the step-by-step effect of that attempt is.  In other words, if you aren't seeing anything in the log, modify the program until you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the answer but I found this Mail wrapper and used it to send email and this works fine :
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android
And do the actual sending in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

If you doing things while your app is in background- android might kill your process any time, especially when it takes time or cpu.
Try doing it with your app stays in the foreground. or do it with a `Sticky Service`

Comment: The app is in the foreground but user isn't typing in the subject or the body of the email. I take info form user make the email body and give a subject to the email and the user just clicks send button on the app.